# Can I replace a sequence of database operations with batch

Tags: java, database

I have checked several examples of executeBatch, but it seems that we can only add one kind of statement in a batch. But I have a problem at hand where I need to execute 2 update queries and then one insert query. Is there a way to do so in a batch.

I have to parse about 100 000 records from a set of XML files and update my database for each of the record. Each record contains a date range which is to be inserted in DB. For example, if I have following 2 records in DB

```
 Record A - range of 1st Jan 2000 to 31st Dec 2010 
 Record B - range of 1st Jan 2011 to 31st Dec 2020
```

Now if the new record comes for following range

```
 Record N - range of 1st Jan 2005 to 31st Jan 2014
```

For adding this record, I need to execute following 2 update queries and one insert query

```
 Update end date of Record A to 31st Jan 2004
 Update start date of Record B to 1st Jan 2015
 Insert record N
```

I want to know if I can have a batch execute 2 update and 1 insert then move to next record and so on.

I can have separate batches for insert and update, but suppose an update is to be done on a record which is yet to be inserted or vice-versa, I will have issues. So the sequence is important. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heterogenous batching is not possible.

If youre using Prepared Statements (as you should), Heterogenous batching wont be possible as PS creation will go haywire trying to bind your variables in update and it wont work. You could however  write a stored procedure that takes

`([RecordIds to update], endupdate, startupdate, startinsert, endinsert ,[other_details])`

as the parameters. Then, after checking your condition execute your procedure with corresponding values which will be

```
RecordAid, endupdate, RecordBid, startupdate, RecordNid, startinsert, endinsert
```

Note: This will eliminate the advantages of batching. It will be as good as executing two updates and then an insert. I would rather recommend batching updates together and running the insert individually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I was hoping to hear but couldn't find it. That being the case, is there any other way to improve the performance. I am already using prepared statements and I cannot go for stored procedure. Any other way I can get a performance improvement or is that it

Comment: As it seems that your order of querying is update->update->insert multiple times and you cant pool all updates and all inserts together. I don't think there's a better solution than using a stored procedure